# PHP Prophecy test void method should be called

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, prophecy

I'm writing some Unit Tests using PHP Prophecy as Mocking Framework.

I'm trying to make a test to assure a void method is called, the code looks something like this:

```
private Prophet $prophet;

protected function setUp()
{
  $this->prophet = new Prophet();
}

protected function tearDown()
{
  $this-prophet->checkPredictions();
}


public function testFoo()
{
  $fooMock = $this->prophet->prophesize(Foo::class);
  $fooMock->execute()->shouldBeCalled();
  $fooMock->reveal();

  ...
}
```

Each time I'm trying to execute the test I'm getting the following error:

`Prophecy\Exception\Call\UnexpectedCallException: Unexpected method call on Double\App\Foo\P1`

On my other test where I check that execute is not called everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: What does the class Foo look like?